# WebTarget post request with unicode characters

Tags: java, unicode, emoji, unicode-string, dialogflow-es

I'm using Api.Ai engine, and Webtarget (java) in order to make a post request with my text, everything works fine, except emojis. I'm sending a unicode character as shown : [image]

but the Api.ai engine gets all the emojis as `ð` character.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have problems with emoticons only, or also with other non-ASCII characters? (eg. accented Latin letters, Greek, Cyrillic, Chinese characters...)

Comment: emoticons only :)

Comment: I am no Java person, but this is maybe related: Are you aware that Java uses two characters (called surrogate characters) to represent code points that lie beyond the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), where most (if not all) emoticons are defined?